# Communicate between Java and JS within Chromium

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome

I want my Java application to communicate with Java Script within a Chromium/Chrome browser. Both runs on the local machine under Ubuntu.

I know this technology from Android (Webkit) called JavaBridge.

How to do this with a native Java application and a "normal" browser? Unfortunately I can't find anything about this yet.  I just need a keyword for further research!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The usual way to do this is to have a web server running in your Java app and just display a website served by that on the browser. Is that not what you meant?

Comment: At the moment, both runs local - Java application and browser. Java downloads content and starts the chromium to display it. Maybe a local webserver is the solution... the things I found so far are all about java applets which are deprecated